# curl_easy_perform() crashing on Ubuntu Server 14

Tags: c++, ubuntu, curl, openssl, libcurl

Here's my upload function.

The goal is: **to upload only a chunk of a file depending on the offset and chunk size**

In this function, if `p_offset` is not zero, I call `fseek()`by myself and then I let libcurl read the contents of the file using `fread()`.

The caller of the function is responsible for giving a correct and valid size of chunk, making sure that `p_offset + p_sizeOfChunk <= ACTUAL_SIZE_OF_FILE`

The answer from the server is supposed to be a string. I get it via my callback `writeToString()`

**The code works fine on Windows and OS X. But `curl_easy_perform()` crashes on sometimes on Ubuntu 14.**

Is there anything in my code that I am missing that could cause this crash?

```
void uploadFile( const string & p_filename, const string & p_url, size_t p_offset, size_t p_sizeOfChunk )
{
    FILE * file( fopen( p_filename.c_str(), "rb" ) );

    if ( !file )
    {
        throw Exception( __FILE__, __LINE__ ) << "Could not open file " << p_filename << " when posting to " << p_url;
    }

    if ( p_offset )
    {
        if ( fseek( file, (long)p_offset, SEEK_SET ) )
        {
            throw Exception( __FILE__, __LINE__ ) << "Could not seek in file " << p_filename << " when posting to " << p_url;
        }
    }

    CURL * curl( curl_easy_init() );

    if ( !curl )
    {
        throw Exception( __FILE__, __LINE__ ) << "Could not initialize cURL when posting " << p_filename << " to " << p_url;
    }

    // URL
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_URL, p_url.c_str() );

    // PUT HTTP method
    string answer;
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, fread );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, file );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeToString );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &answer );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)p_sizeOfChunk );

    char errorBuffer[ CURL_ERROR_SIZE + 1 ];
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer );

    // No signal handlers...
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1 );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 120000 );

    // HEADER
    char contentLength[ 512 ];
    snprintf( contentLength, sizeof( contentLength ), "Content-Length: %zu", p_sizeOfChunk );

    struct curl_slist * headers( nullptr );
    headers = curl_slist_append( headers, contentLength );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers );

    // SSL
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "path/to/cacert.pem" );

    CURLcode res( curl_easy_perform( curl ) );

    fclose( file );

    if ( res != CURLE_OK && res != CURLE_SEND_ERROR )
    {
        curl_easy_cleanup( curl );
        throw Exception( __FILE__, __LINE__ ) << "cURL error when posting " << p_filename << " to " << p_url << ": " << errorBuffer;
    }

    long httpResponseCode( 0 );
    curl_easy_getinfo( curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpResponseCode );
    curl_easy_cleanup( curl );

    if ( ( httpResponseCode / 100 ) != 2 )
    {
        cout << answer << endl;
        throw Exception( __FILE__, __LINE__ ) << "HTTP error " << httpResponseCode << " when posting " << p_filename;
    }
}
```

I get the answer and record it on a `std::string` with `writeToString()`. It's for sure not the reason for the crash. I tested it just returning the `size * count` and the crash still happens.

```
static size_t writeToString( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream )
{
    string & retContent( *( reinterpret_cast< string * >( stream ) ) );

    if ( !retContent.length() )
    {
        int skipBOM( ( reinterpret_cast< const unsigned char * >( ptr )[ 0 ] == 0xEF && reinterpret_cast< const unsigned char * >( ptr )[ 1 ] == 0xBB && reinterpret_cast< const unsigned char * >( ptr )[ 2 ] == 0xBF ) ? 3 : 0 );
        retContent += string( static_cast< const char * >( ptr ) + skipBOM, static_cast< int >( size * count ) - skipBOM );
    }
    else
    {
        retContent += string( static_cast< const char * >( ptr ), size * count );
    }

    return size * count;
}
```

Here is the stack in the moment of crash! It seems to be related to OpenSSL.

```
#0  0x00007ffff65ad35d in write () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0x00007ffff73187a6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#2  0x00007ffff731684b in BIO_write () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#3  0x00007ffff6ffcb72 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#4  0x00007ffff6ffd273 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#5  0x00007ffff76873e1 in ossl_send (conn=0x7ffef8013b28, sockindex=0, mem=0x7ffef8005379, len=16384, curlcode=0x7fff127fa5c0) at vtls/openssl.c:2720
#6  0x00007ffff762fe0f in Curl_write (conn=0x7ffef8013b28, sockfd=64, mem=0x7ffef8005379, len=16384, written=0x7fff127fa608) at sendf.c:233
#7  0x00007ffff764fb01 in readwrite_upload (data=0x7ffef8000a78, conn=0x7ffef8013b28, k=0x7ffef8000af0, didwhat=0x7fff127fa664) at transfer.c:954
#8  0x00007ffff764fdd9 in Curl_readwrite (conn=0x7ffef8013b28, done=0x7fff127fa6dc) at transfer.c:1059
#9  0x00007ffff765ced7 in multi_runsingle (multi=0x7ffef800a668, now=..., data=0x7ffef8000a78) at multi.c:1484
#10 0x00007ffff765d60c in curl_multi_perform (multi_handle=0x7ffef800a668, running_handles=0x7fff127fa870) at multi.c:1759
#11 0x00007ffff7652103 in easy_transfer (multi=0x7ffef800a668) at easy.c:705
#12 0x00007ffff7652311 in easy_perform (data=0x7ffef8000a78, events=false) at easy.c:793
#13 0x00007ffff7652364 in curl_easy_perform (easy=0x7ffef8000a78) at easy.c:812
#14 ...
```

Comment: where is crashing? have you tried running it under gdb?

Comment: Unrelated: your snippet leaks like crazy whenever you throw an exception (`file` should be closed at each `throw` site). For this common pattern, I advise the use of a guard: instantiate a little object whose destructor will execute an action whatever the exit path of the function. You can then use this guard to properly release the `file` and `curl` handles.

Comment: @jsantander ... I tried GDB already... the crash seems to be related to OpenSSL, once I am uploading it via HTTPS. I will update the question with the stack.

Comment: Perhaps you can recompile with debug-version libraries and including symbols (-g). Alternatively, could you try to distill your program into an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/)? we could then try it ourselves...

Comment: It's kinda strange nobody in the world has come to the same stack as me. libcurl is supposed to be "popular" enough to someone else know this stack before... but it seems really nobody knows... I will recompile cURL (and OpenSSL) and debug it. Thank you.

Comment: no need to recompile, you can pull the libXXX-dev packages...

Comment: I just figure out what happened... more stupid than this... thanks for the help! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in a detail that I've completely misunderstood.

```
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1 );
```

The effect of `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL` **prevents** libcurl from handling any signals! My original interpretation was completely the inverse. The mistake happened because on OS X it's working [and the pipe handling also exists], so I assumed that the "signal management" was correct. I don't know why on OS X the same bug didn't show up. Anyways, I removed this line and it's working perfectly.

And, of course, another possible solution is to explicit set ir to zero:

```
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing... run it with the debugger (or get a proper core dump) to find out where is really failing.

Not sure if this might be the problem... but looking at the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html), the function you pass in `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` must have the following signature.

```
size_t function( char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
```

However in your case:

```
size_t writeToString(const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream);
```

Apparently the default implementation for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION expects a FILE * there... but in void * form

Comment: I tried it already. But cURL always accepted fread/fwrite functions as callback. Therefore it should not be an issue. These signatures are equivalent in the assembly level... I will update my question with the stack... it seems to be related to OpenSSL